# Can't dismiss push notification shown in app

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am sending push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging to both Android and iOS devices. On Android everything works as expected. On iOS I can also receive the notifications but I have a rather strange issue on my iPhone. What I do:

1. Close my app.
2. Send test notification from Firebase console to my iOS device.
3. Receive notification on iPhone.
4. Tap on the notification to open my app.

Now, the app opens as expected. **But for some reason the notification is now shown inside the app as an Alert (or something similar). And it is not possible to dismiss it!**

Here are some screenshots of this process:

[image: Push notification as it should be]
[image: Open the notification]
[image: Push notification shown in-app which can't be dismissed]

When executing the same steps on my Android device, the app opens as well, but there is no Alert shown or anything. The app starts just as usual.

**My goal is to remove this in-app notification. I just want the app to start as usual when tapping the push notification.**

Tested on an `iPhone 6` with `iOS 12.3.1`.

Using `"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.4"` with `"react-native": "^0.59.9"`.

**Custom app code:**

I don't have any special app-side code except for asking the user for the required permissions to receive push notifications and getting the firebase messaging token.

**What I already tried to do:**

Define an `onMessage` handler to eventually override any default handler that is creating this Alert. Did not help anything.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of notification itself. Its because of the alert you presented.

Each alert must have at least one button generated using `UIAlertAction`.

Alerts (and actionsheets) automatically dismiss on any button touch up inside action. So no need for extra code to dismiss, But you **MUST** specify at least one `UIAlertAction` for your `UIAlertController`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I also thought it might be because of missing action buttons, so I tried sending different values in the `action-loc-key` field of my message. It did not help though. However, because of your hint I found that the issue was some custom code from the previous developers on this project as I am relatively new to the code base. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I would post the code if I was a React-Native programmer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what the problem was - once more posted here just a little bit too soon...

The origin of this in-app alert was simply some **custom code** in the `AppDelegate.m` I did not know about as I am relatively new to this project's code base.

In detail, there was this method `showPush`, which was called in various handlers responsible for receiving push notifications:

```
- (void)showPush: (id)userInfo {
  NSString *title = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"title"];
  NSString *message = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"body"];
  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
  [[[self window] rootViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

**After removing this custom code everything works as expected.**